# C++ class template specialization question

Tags: c++, templates, specialization, template-specialization

By looking at the following code, I am confused by line 3.
Line 3 is not a special case of the base template, it is more like a "class overload". But it can be compiled successfully.
The obj1 in line 7 is defined according to line 3, but failed to compile.
How come?

```
template<typename S,int T, void(* U)()> class Bar{};  // Base template
template<int T, void(* U)()> class Bar<double, T, U>{}; // Specialization, which is good
template<int T, void(* U)()> class Bar<double, U, T>{}; // Also good, how come?

void func(){};
int main(){
   //Bar<double, func, 1> obj1;   // Error, from line 3
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as that form is not used anywhere - then the compiler will not complain. If it is used, and the compiler has to instantiate - then it will complain. Which is why if you uncomment, you get the error - at this point, the compiler sees the flawed partial specialization.

Comment: Then when should the compiler complain, when should it not? If I add another line at line 4:     template<int T, void(* U)()> class Bar<double, U, T, T>{};  It is not used, and the compiler does not instantiate, but it failed to compile.

Comment: @John, like I said, it will complain if you try to declare an instance of that type (as in uncomment the line of `obj1`) (at which point it tries to instantiate). It won't if you don't - that's the beauty of templates...

Comment: @John, that's a different problem - there you have more template parameters than `Bar` requires.

Comment: Thanks. I'll remember it as the rule. still feel the rule does not make sense though :)

Comment: @John Crane - it may seem to not make sense, in this particular case, but it's actually very useful to allow some definitions in templates that should not compile for certain types.

Comment: The compiler is allowed (but not required) to complain if you have a template that can *never* be used. This might be one of those.

Answer (score 4):

Templates are special:  anything that you do not use is not actually instantiated (compiled).  This allows many cool things to be done with certain generic templates.  For example, you could define member functions that simply would not compile with certain type parameters, but as long as you would not use those members, no error.

This can also bite you:  Line 3 isn't actually well-formed - it's a non-compiling specialization of Bar - but you won't notice it until you actually try to use it, in your main() function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please see my comments following Nim below.